# ASP.NET MVC support for HTML output (as opposed to XHTML)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

It seems to me that ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers only output XHTML-like tags (closed empty elements), which is not valid HTML.

Is there support for HTML output in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True... it'll output typically:

```
<input type="text />
```

You could certainly write your own HTML Helpers to cover any cases you want.

Answer (score 2):

As pcampbell hinted, you probably need to write your own Html helper to do this. However, it doesn't have to be too hard - if you notice you need one, for example for an `<input>` element, you could simply do this:

```
 public static class Html4Extensions
     public string Html4TextBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
     {
         return helper.TextBox(name).Replace("/>", ">");
     }
 }
```

And then you do the same for every overload you need.