# How to prevent ASP.NET MVC from removing closing tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

I have a View in an ASP.NET MVC Project (version 5.2.3.0) which is well-formed; or at least tags such as `<p>` and `<li>` all have closing tags. When it is rendered all the closing tags are removed. I have performed raw captures using Fiddler and PostMan and in each case the resulting markup had the closing tags removed.

I assumed this may relate to something like XHTML Conformance Levels so I changed the configuration to set strict rules (e.g. `<xhtmlConformance mode="Strict"/>`) but this did not resolve the issue.

How do I configure ASP.NET MVC to stop automatically stripping out my closing tags, in this case is it corrupting other processes?

For context... I am not intending to follow XHTML per se, I just need a few select views to be rendered unaltered. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Blaming the behavior "on MVC" isn't very helpful. There are many different ways to render HTML. What specific method are you using in this case? What tags are not closed (you only list the ones that are)? Do note that you can use the [TagBuilder](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers) to create your own HTML helpers with closing tags (the ToString method has an overload that allows you to control the behavior). Or, you can just put the HTML elements along with their closing tags into the view.

Comment: Good point, let me clarify... I have statically placed elements which I have put into the View file. The layout is limited to html, head, and body tags. The body content is quite small and In all cases; except "<br />" tags; the elements are closed (Ex. "<p>...</p><br /><p>...</p>") which then renders as "<p>...<br /><p>...". I am working to isolate but have not found any obviously suspects yet. We are not manipulating the content at any point in the rendering process.

Comment: My question is, what is the "rendering process"? Are you using HTML helpers? Are you using some other way to generate the HTML? Please post some code. Unless you provide a way to replicate the behavior, this question may be closed. Do note that [closing tags for `<p>` are optional and they may not be nested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23361330/181087), but AFAIK, [MVC HTML helpers output XHTML by default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/967256/181087).

Comment: Can I ask, are you putting these into a cshtml file?

Comment: @Worthy7 Yes, these are in cshtml files.

Comment: So they are actually being compiled at build time. Have you tried using a normal HTML file? Sorry I could check this myself but I don't have VS installed right now.